# Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document'

Tags: angular

vendor.bundle.js:119122 ERROR DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': 'javascript:;' is not a valid selector.
    at Object.getSelectorFromElement (http://localhost:4200/scripts.bundle.js:12:1466)
    at Function.c._getParentFromElement (http://localhost:4200/scripts.bundle.js:12:23736)
    at HTMLDocument.c._clearMenus (http://localhost:4200/scripts.bundle.js:12:23131)
    at HTMLDocument.dispatch (http://localhost:4200/scripts.bundle.js:4:10316)
    at HTMLDocument.q.handle (http://localhost:4200/scripts.bundle.js:4:8343)
    at Object.trigger (http://localhost:4200/scripts.bundle.js:5:5628)
    at HTMLSpanElement. (http://localhost:4200/scripts.bundle.js:5:6138)

Comment: what is Document?
where is your code?

Comment: Fix the selector.

Comment: first and foremost dont use jquery with angular , it will get you sometime in the future  . If you want to use document then `import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';`  and then use   ` constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) document) { }`

Comment: can you update the question with your code.